# $f$ is continuous in $a$ if and only if $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$

Tags: limits, continuity

Another one from Stewart Calculus, 8E:

> Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$.

I realise that an iff statement is just a combination of two if-then statements, so I began by breaking the question down into two smaller ones:

1) If $f$ is continuous, then $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$.

2) If $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$, then $f$ is continuous.

You see, I can't get my head past the definition of continuity. Is it acceptable to simply say that the conclusion follows from the premise by definition? Since we have to assume that $f$ is continuous, I can't see any way that the limit at any point *wouldn't* be equal to the function there (if it's defined, which again by definition is the case).

Likewise, if we take it for granted that there exists for every $\epsilon>0$ a corresponding $\delta$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ (taking $x=a+h$), then again it seems we reach the desired conclusion via our definitions. Does it come down to showing that the other half of continuity (that $f(a)$ be defined; limits don't talk about functions *exactly* at a point) follows from the limit itself?

I really want to understand the mechanics behind this proof. It feels so fundamental that I can't help but imagine that understanding it would really broaden my horizons.

Comment: Actually the statement is not quite correct (unless there are assumptions about $D_f$ that you are not quoting). It should be “$f$ is continuous at $a$ iff $\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h) = f(x)$ or $a$ is an isolated point of the domain $D_f$”. Cf. this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not as simple.

I'll use the sequential definitions of limit and continuity (not $\varepsilon-\delta$ ones).

Assume that $f$ is continuous at $a$. Let $(h_n)$ be a sequence such that $h_n\to 0$. Define $a_n = a + h_n$. We have that $\lim_n a_n = \lim_n(a+h_n) = \lim_n a + \lim_n h_n = a$. Thus, by the assumption, $\lim_n f(a+h_n) = \lim_n f(a_n) = f(a)$. Since $(h_n)$ was arbitrary, we conclude $\lim_{h\to 0} f(a+h) = f(a)$.

Now, assume that $\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h) = f(a)$. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_n\to a$. Define $h_n = a_n - a$. We have that $\lim_nh_n = \lim_n (a_n-a) = \lim_n a_n-\lim_na = a - a = 0$. Thus, by the assumption, $\lim_n f(a_n) = \lim_n f(a + h_n) = f(a)$. Since $(a_n)$ was arbitrary, we conclude $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$, and we are done.

This can be summarized in two key facts: $x\mapsto x + a$ is a continuous bijection and composition of two continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Wow, that was a great answer! I'm going to have fun absorbing this. It already feels so much clearer.

Comment: @Marcus, thank you. I've cleaned it up a bit to make it more uniform.